# Getting warning during using "sencha app watch"

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I tried to solve this problem using some cases like reinstall sencha cmd, but didn't got solution still now.

See below screenshot of warnings.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks @N. Jadhav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

- If you do have remote packages make sure Sencha Cmd has writing permissions to the repository
- If you do not have remote packages (and the warnings are unexpected), try removing any repository connection using: `sencha package repo remove <name>`, and even the sencha package (`sencha package repo remove sencha`)

PS: Run `sencha package repo` for more commands.

Answer (score 0):

Do like what the message suggest you.

> Removing local package ...